# Delete non utf8 characters in Eclipse using regex

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

Is there a possibility to do that in Eclipse? I have a lot of non utf8 characters like sch�ma or propri�t� (it's french :)). For now, I am deleting those characters hand. How can I remove those characters?

Comment: Question: In your source code?

Comment: Yes, they are in the comments. But they fail at compilation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters are in the UTF-8 character set.

Either the text is encoded incorrectly or you have your file encoding set incorrectly in Eclipse.

Try right clicking the file -> properties. Then check the text file encoding is set to UTF-8, if its not, select Other and change it to UTF-8.

Comment: @Dimitri Files can inherit their character encoding from the project or be set individually.  It wouldn't hurt to double check they are inheriting UTF-8 like they should be.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a little program that reads a file, removes all `char` > 127 and write back to the file.
[I would pass the file names as command line arguments]